Calculating the degree of an involution of the n-simplex
Let $i:\Delta^n\to\Delta^n$ be the linear map defined by sending the vertex $i$ to $n-i$ for all $0\le i\le n$. I want to calculate the degree of the restriction $i:S^{n-1}\cong\partial\Delta^n\to\partial\Delta^n\cong S^{n-1}$. I know that since i is an involution then the induced map $i_\ast:\mathbb{Z}\cong H_{n-1}(\partial\Delta^n)\to H_{n-1}(\partial\Delta^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is also an involution so $\text{deg}i=\pm1$ and I suspect that the sign will depend on $n$ but other than that I don't know how to proceed. Do I need to construct an explicit generator for $H_{n-1}(\partial\Delta^n)$ and check how $i$ acts on it in homology or is there a way to deduce the sign without such an explicit calculation?
Edit: Thanks to Jonathan's comment I realized that I can write $i$ as a composition of reflections and I understand the intuition for why the degree of a reflection of the $n-$simplex is $-1$ but I'm having a lot of trouble proving this formally. I have been able to show that $H_{n-1}(\partial\Delta^n)$ is generated by the class of $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\delta_i$ where $\delta_i:\Delta^{n-1}\to\partial\Delta^n,\,(t_0,\ldots t_{n-1})\mapsto (t_0,\ldots,t_{i-1},0,t_{i},\ldots,t_{n-1})$. I need to show that if $\tau_j:\partial\Delta^n\to\partial\Delta^n$ is the map transposing the vertices $j,n-j$ (assuming that they are different) then the class of $\left[\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\tau_j\circ\delta_i\right]=-\left[\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\delta_i\right]$ in homolog. Trying to prove that, I soon realized that the calculations become very cumbersome. For example, I started by calculating the classes of $\tau_0\circ\delta_i$ for $n=2$ to get some intuition and was able to see that, for example, $[\tau_0\circ\delta_0]=-[\delta_2]$ but to prove this I need to construct a map $\Phi:\Delta^2\to\partial\Delta^2$ s.t.$\partial\Phi=\tau_0\circ\delta_0+\delta_2$. Doing this for general $n,i,j$ seems a very inefficient way to show that the degree of a reflection is $-1$ and I would like to know if there is a better way to show this fact.

I'm not fully sure what your map is. Does the $i$th vertex go to $n-1$ and the $n-1$th vertex go to $i$, i.e. you interchange them? With all other vertices fixed?

Oops yeah I made a typo, the map sends the vertex $i$ to the vertex $n-i$ for all $0\le i \le n$

Can you write your map as the composition of a bunch of reflections, each of which transposes just two vertices?
